# Extensible parser design

Tags: c++, parsing

I have a class `Target` with a "fileType" `enum` which holds all kinds of files my parser needs to know about (currently SOURCE, HEADER, RESOURCE). I'd like my Parsing function to be able to do something generic like:

```
if( token == some_known_fileType )
    put_nextToken_in_the_list_for_that_fileType();
else
    return an_error();
```

But there's a catch: I'd like to be able to simply extend the known fileTypes with subclasses of `Target`, that extend the `enum` in a correct way, see [Base enum class inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644629/base-enum-class-inheritance) for how I did this. I don't want to modify the above code, but only generically extend the Target half. C++0X may be required and is very welcome.

Thanks!

**UPDATE:** Upon trying to explain it here and posting some reduced class declarations, I realised my design is broken, and I tried to push the specialization of fileType too deep in my class structure. I wanted only one place to store a full list of all known types, but in trying to do so, I accidentally forced the design to have access to that list in two places at a time. I now realise that the list of all fileTypes should be where the keywords SOURCE, HEADER, etc. are read, and be handled *generically from thereon. I will store a full list in one place, and access that list through a "huge" `enum` later on. A `std::map<fileType, std::set<std::string> >` pops into my head as a logical choice here, instead of seperately named `set` for each specific `fileType`. Thanks for the braincandy in your responses though! Any thoughts are still welcome.

Comment: Would you mind adding a bit more of your code. I'm unsure what it is you want to do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is not usually the right approach, but that's my belief. I would do this in a different way.
Take a step back and what are we trying to achieve, we want to control the behavior based on an incoming (input parameter) value.
Lets say we have classes: FileA FileB ...
the file_type holds the type of file.
Use a factory to control the available list of files (which can change based on the registration of different files).

```
class FileA {
    void register_type();  // register itself to the factory.
};

class FileB..
//main code
class FileFactoryDelegator {
    ...
    delegateControl (FileType file_type) {
        //validate file_type.
        file_types[file_type]->performFileOperation (..);
    }
};
```

Instead of if-else loop.

```
file_factory.delegateControl (token);
```

Comment: Well, this is actually what I implemented eventually through a `std::map<Target::fileType, std::set<std::string> >`, which is much more flexible than I thought before. Thanks! (I had no need for fileType registration, and always have all of them available, also `std::map::operator[]` creates an element if it was not present yet, which is only a bonus for me!)

Answer (score 0):

This is hard to answer as a lot depends on what exactly your are doing with the tokens, file type values, and Target instances. However, I think the underlying theme here is that you need to replace if() statements with virtual method calls. For example, your code fragment could end up being

```
if (tokenLists.supportsFileType(token))
    tokenLists.getListForType(token).put_nextToken_into_this_list();
else
    return an_error();
```

The above tokenLists example could be generalized into a registry of TargetSpecificLogic instances, which combine all kinds of filetype specific methods.

You Target class could implement a virtual method `retrieveAllKnownFileTypes()`, which the subclasses would extend, and which the rest of your code could evaluate.

You Target class could implement a virtual method `bool isFileTypeKnown(filetype)`, returning `true` or `false`.

...and so on.

Answer (score -1):

don't write your parser. use [boost::spirit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spirit_Parser_Framework)