# How to inherit typedef declarations for enum type

Tags: c++

I am trying to inherit typedef declarations for enum type from base class in derived class

```
class Base{
public:
    enum Type{
        UNSPECIFIED = 0,
        TYPE1,
        TYPE2
    }
};

class Derived : public Base{
public:
    enum Type{
        UNSPECIFIED = 0,
        TYPE1,
        TYPE2,
        TYPE3
    }
};
```

How do we extend the `enum` type declaration in the derived class?

Comment: You can't "extend" it. Once a type is defined, it's set in stone. However, `Derived` can define its own `enum Type`, but it's important to know that it is different from `Base::Type`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't extend enums in C++ by inheritance.  Not part of the language spec.

Some other ideas on how to do something like what you want here:
[Base enum class inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644629/base-enum-class-inheritance)