# Deriving from an enum in C++

Tags: c++, enums, c++17

Is it possible to derive from an enum, if so how?

For instance:

```
enum eStandardTypes
{
    Type1 = 0,
    Type2,
    Unknown,
    Count,
};

enum eExtendedTypes : eStandardTypes
{
    Type3 = eStandardTypes::Count,
    Unknown,
    Count,
};
```

Comment: I think you mean *inherit*. And no it's not possible.

Comment: Upvoted for intrigue. If it was good enough for a C++ standards discussion, then it's good enough to be asked here.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That's what I meant.

Comment: @GainPaolo Did the search, nothing popped up that looked like this question, but it sure does look like a duplicate.

Comment: @GianPaolo you dont need to "downvote as duplicated" but just flag the question. Imho being a duplicate isnt a reason for downvote

Comment: @tobi303: Especially given that the OP clearly is not au fait with the terminology; do study the question edits.

Comment: Can't create a class as showned at the [stated duplicate as](https://stackoverflow.com/a/644639/7880546) because of I am using an external (open sourced) library. That would break the conventions of that library. Made a comment as I agree on the duplicate. Gave me the answer too.

Comment: downvote removed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No this is not possible, even with `enum` classes.

Support for inheritance of `enum` classes was discussed for C++17, but was not incorporated into that standard.